# Converting any array of numbers to values between 1 and 100

Tags: limits, combinatorial-group-theory

I have several arrays of numbers. I need to convert each number in them to a value between 1 and 100. The lowest value in each array should be 1. The highest value in each array should be 100.

I can get a value between 0 and 100 by using $X$ = value, $Y$ = Array Min, $Z$ = Array Max:
$$\frac{X-Y}{Z-Y}*100$$
The answer to my riddle appears to be reducing the size of $Y$ (Array Min) by some small amount.
If my math is correct, solving for A in the following equation should give me my answer.
Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve for A.
$$\frac{Y-YA}{Z-YA}*100=1$$
So, my question is: What does $A$ equal? What is the logic required to solve for it?

Comment: To get the values between $1$ and $100$ you need to consider $1+\frac{X-Y}{Z-Y}*99$ instead of reducing the side of $Y$.

Comment: You can solve for A by multiplying both sides of the equation by Z-YA, and then after a bit more simplification get A = (100Y-Z)/99Y. And if you then actually replace Y by YA in your original expression and simplify it, you will get exactly what @jjagmath wrote above.